# Disable Resharper localization inspection in visual studio ASP.NET solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, localization, resharper

I have a large website solution in visual studio comprised of an ASP.NET Website project, and many class library projects. I'm looking for a way to either:

1. Disable ReSharper localization completely, or;
2. Force "English" as the default, and only language

The solution is an internal application to our organization, with zero chance of ever being localized. At the same time I use `StyleCop` and `ReSharper` for code style management, and am sick of being littered with "String can/should be localized" warnings, etc. I can turn some of the warnings off in the StyleCop and Resharper settings, however I'd rather just specify English as the only language, etc.

I thought there was a way in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file for each class library project to specify English only, etc. but can't seem to find out how online so perhaps I'm off base there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found the answer after the fact at least in terms of Resharper, and figured it may help others down the road.

Just select each project and press F4 (or bring up the properties window). There is an option for `Localizable` with options for `Default`, `Yes` and `No`.

Select `No` and you're good to go. Resharper will honor this and stop inspecting every string, etc.

[image: Resharper Localization Options]